# Setting a tenant before making calls to create object in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

We are using Rails 7

We are trying to test some objects that are tenant'ed. So, we need to create a tenant and set that tenant before any other objects are created. I am unsure of how to structure that.

Here is what doesn't work:

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe Store, type: :model do
  before do
    @tenant = FactoryBot.create(:tenant)
    Tenant.set_current_tenant(@tenant)
  end
  
  describe "associations" do
    let(:customer) { FactoryBot.create(:customer) }
  end
end
```

This throws an `InvalidTenantAccess` because the tenant has not been set when the `let` call is made.

How to structure this?

Comment: Do you use some public libs to implement a multi-tenancy or implement it by self? It is not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, we use `Milia`, but that's not really important. What is important is that it needs to be set up before the `let` is called. How to make a call before `let`?

Comment: `before` hook takes precedence over `let` call. So it isn't a reason of error. However your original question much more complex than question about `before` and `let` hooks order. @phil

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tenancy. But, this looks like a problem in the RSpec and/or factories. If there is a relationship between the tenant and the customer, then tenant should be created as part of the customer factory, not independently in the `before` hook. Also, it's generally not a good practice to use instance variables in RSpec. It's a great way to make a bunch of flaky tests. This is why `let` exists.

Comment: `before` block is called before `let`. Your error is somewhere else. You could see the order of execution if you put a byebug in your before, and another byebug in your let block. Maybe you have another `before` block above this one that makes use of `customer` "variable" or something

Comment: any news for us @phil ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue I was having had nothing to do with this bit of code. It was actually the Factory for `customer` (and other factories).

Because of the way the `tenant` is associated to `acts_as_tenant` models you CANNOT put a tenant in the factory.

So *this* is bad:

```
# spec/factories/customers.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :customer do
    tenant
    ....
  end
end
```

This will cause RSpec to try to create a tenant. Also, even passing IN a tenant will not work.

The solution?
Leave it out:

```
# spec/factories/customers.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :customer do
    ....
  end
end
```

Then you can do something like this in your spec

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.describe Store, type: :model do
  fixtures(:marketplaces)

  before(:all) do
    @tenant ||= FactoryBot.create(:tenant)
    Tenant.set_current_tenant(@tenant)
  end

  describe "validations" do
    let(:customer) { FactoryBot.create(:customer) }

    #your checks
  end
end
```

All will be fine. You definitely need to set up a tenant before, but that's all.